# Modeling Temporal-Interval Distance

Tags: record-linkage, temporal-difference

I'm trying to define a model for comparing temporal intervals, and can't find an appropriate distance function that incorporates the different relations two temporal intervals might have, e.g. overlap, contain, ...

Computing the distance between the edges of the intervals is not enough since we might lose information regarding how the two intervals relate.

The distance score can be represented as a vector and not restricted to be a singular value.

The distance will then be used with other attributes to estimate the similarity between different records.

Is there a well-defined model that can be used to help solve such a problem?  Thank you.

Comment: One could propose many solutions (literally any metric defined on the plane would satisfy your stated requirements, because intervals are, after all, just ordered pairs of numbers), but you haven't provided any information we could use to determine which of these, if any, might be suitable for your problem.  Could you explain what property of the time intervals you are attempting to capture with this distance?

Comment: @whuber I'm trying to capture the ontological relation between the two intervals and also how far away are they from each other. i.e., measuring a degree of overlap between the intervals, or in how much proportion is one interval is contained in the other, if there is any.  Maybe intersection/union would be a useful metric to achieve this  with an additional metric to compute the actual difference between the edges of interval?

Comment: Unforunately, the phrases "ontological relation" and "actual difference" don't tell us anything.  We need to know how you plan to use or interpret this metric.  Your comments about overlap and proportion hint at some possibilities but don't pin it down. For instance, "degree of overlap" could be any increasing function of the length of intersection or that length relative to some measure of the combined length of the two intervals. For an indication of one small set of the possibilities, see [Wikipedia on the Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index).

Comment: One interpretation of such a metric is to perform blocking on records in order to apply record linkage and relation discovery afterward. Basically, I have a system that already does such functions, but not on temporal intervals. Another interpretation is to perform clustering on such records. Important to note here is that records contain different attributes types with their own distance functions.